# Change of IP Address

Tags: wp-admin, ip

I have a site developed by a third party using wordpress however we could not log in the Admin page currently due to change of IP address recently.

The login page https://domain/wp-admin has directed me to "Forbidden" error page instead.

I also do not have the database file to do further amendments.

Can anyone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to update the DNS to point to the new IP, you only need to make changes to WP if the URL has changed

Comment: Don't you have any access to hosting ?

Comment: @SabbirHasan Unfortunately no, as we are riding on third party host.

Comment: I'm  able to access the login page of the website. You can message me the credential if you want me to check. I'll happily do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may try changing the site url in wp-config.php with:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

you may also check if you have http, or https.

Comment: What if I do not have the working files for the site? The person who helped us with the designing did not leave any working files for us, so I'm unable to edit on wp-config.php. By the way, wit is using https.

Comment: @regine06 you can gain access via the hosting panel, you should contact support to gain access if you don't have it. I suspect this isn't a WP issue but a DNS issue, so this is unlikely to be something you can fiix from WP Admin or by changing PHP files. If we knew what the domain name was and what the IP is supposed to be then anybody could test if that was the case

Comment: @TomJNowell Could you help to test if I can provide the domain name and IP address? www.gtl.com.sg (IP address is 172.25.200.240)

Comment: The A record of that doman is `103.11.191.71`, look at https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=www.gtl.com.sg&rtype=ANY, you should speak with your webhosts support to confirm with them what the correct IP on that record should be, and how to update it to point to the correct place, it looks lke the domain is managed with Vodien.com. You'll also want to speak with them if they aren't also your webhost for how to update it. Think of it like an address book, you look up gtl.com.sg and the A record is the GPS coordinates to head towards the server that powers your site

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue when accessing the /WP-admin from an IP address in another country. The hosting company had blocked entry from IP addresses in other locations. Please contact your host to fix.